# Unterschiedliche Flexionen im Possessivum

Tags: inflection, morphology

Mir ist aufgefallen, daß Adjektiva und Possessiva unterschiedlich pronomial flektieren, was im Genitiv masculinum bzw. neutrum sichtbar wird, zB:

> der Geruch sein**es** Wassers
> der Geruch frisch**en** Wassers

Hat jemand eine Erklärung für dieses Phänomen, bzw. eine Regel, die das erfaßt? Intuitiv weiß ich schon, was richtig ist, aber mich würde interessieren, wie man das jemandem, der Deutsch lernt, beibringt.

Meine Vermutung (aber die ist eben ungesichert, ich bin kein Linguist) ist, daß das Possessivpronomen hier eine Art Artikel darstellt (ich glaube, der Ausdruck dafür ist "Determinativ").

Comment: by googling "Geruch frischen" vs "Geruch eines frischen" I found that the first one is used more but it seems that the other is also used quite normally, or is it not?

Comment: @Andra: that is not the point. The point is that in "seines Wassers" "seines" is used in the place of an Adjektiv, the same as in "frischen Wassers". Still "sein" and "frisch" inflect differently (one strong, one weak) and this different inflection is what the question is about.

Comment: so I'm "jemand, der Deutsch lernt" but my question would rather be why "eines" (inflected the same way as "seines") is omitted in the second example

Comment: @Andra: it is omitted because it has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pronomen (einschließlich Possessive) und Adjektive werden im Deutschen unterschiedlich flektiert. Pronomen werden nicht wie Adjektive mal stark, mal schwach dekliniert abhängig von der Präsenz eines Artikelworts, sondern sie haben ihre eigene Deklination, die im Wesentlichen der starken Deklination der Adjektive entspricht.

Beim Genitiv Singular weicht die Deklination der Pronomen von der starken Deklination der Adjektive ab: Das Adjektiv verwendet -en, während das Pronomen -es verwendet. Vor einigen Jahrhunderten war hier auch bei den Adjektiven noch die Endung -es üblich.

Allgemein kann man beobachten, dass die schwache Endung -en sich ausbreitet und allmählich auch auf die Pronomen übergreift. So hört man heute zunehmend den Genitiv *diesen Jahres*, wo früher ausschließlich *dieses Jahres* korrekt war.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Um sicherzugehen, daß ich das richtig verstanden habe; "vor einigen Jahrhunderten" war es also "frisches Wassers" anstatt "frischen Wassers"?

Comment: @bakunin richtig, siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Deklination_der_Adjektive